# Using Lua How to read or write in different directory?

Tags: file, lua, subdirectory

I am able to create write read and append in same directory using Lua.  Now I want to write to a sub directory. Can someone please show?  Thx. 
I.e. Existing Current dir:  C:\main
Existing subdirectory:      C:\main\sub
New file:                   C:\main\sub\newfile.txt

Answer (score 3):

Writing into a sub-directory is no different from writing into a file in the same directory. The only issue you may run into is with escaping Windows path separators, so instead of `"C:\main"`, use `[[C:\main]]` or `"C:\\main"`.

If the folder needs to be created, you'll need to use shell commands or [lfs](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) library as the default Lua interpreter doesn't provide API to create folders.

Comment: You may also use forward slashes even on Windows as it works great.